# React disable all events. How to ignore `onClick` & `onChange` props when generating DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I wish to display a react component and its children in 'consultation' mode. It means removing automatically all `onClick`, `onChange` , ... props from `<div>` & co. I wish to do that temporary to have my Component come back to life when wanted.

How can I do that without MANUALLY, in each sub components, condition the use of `onClick` & `onChange`? I search a way to say "Hey react, ignore the `onClick` & `onChange` props when generating DOM for all those components".

Any idea how to do that? I am opened to alternative solutions that will avoid event to trigger on DOM element at the end.

Comment: Use your own `React.createElement` wrapper which conditionally strips out those props. Or a wrapper component which does that (working with `this.props.children`).

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, you may need to wrap your functions with another, and then you could control the enabling/disabling from a single point.

```
function activable(cb) {
  return function wrap(...args) {
    if (process.env.ENABLE_ACTIONS) {
      return cb(...args);
    }
  }
}

function MyComponent() {
   // It's better to pass in anon functions to our activable function so
   // that our function maintains it's scope.  Otherwise you would need
   // to bind the scope. Only if needed I guess, but good to be aware of.
   const onClick = activatable((e) => {
      console.log(e.target);
   });
   return (<button onClick={onClick}>do</button>);
}
```

So yeah a bit of manual set up initially, but then easily controlled.

---

Here is a running example: http://www.webpackbin.com/EJsecCwXW

Go to the `main.js` file and then change the `enableActions` flag at the top, save and then press the button.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It should work yes but, knowing that there is thouthand of components in the app, this solution is to eavy to be praticable. I need a solution that requires minimal changes inside code.

Comment: Write a babel plugin? :)

Comment: https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook 
In all seriousness this would get you there.

Comment: This solution nevers occurs to me but could be a good one. I am going to investigate